# How to fix 'Display First Content on loading'

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a list of 4 logos. Content will display based on selecting the logo. I need first logo content to be displayed upon loading the application. I am Using Angular 7 for my application. How do i resolve the issue?
Please find the code below

```
<div class="section-logos">
    <ul class="tem-icons">
        <li *ngFor="let phenomTem of phenomTems"
          [class.selected]="phenomTem === selectedTem"
          (click)="onSelect(phenomTem)" class="col-md" >
            <img src="{{ phenomTem.logoPath }}" alt="Logos">
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedTem" class="section-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <small>{{selectedTem.sectionSubTitle}}</small>
            <h2>{{selectedTem.sectionTitle}}</h2>
            <p>{{ selectedTem.sectionDescription }}</p>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img src="{{ selectedTem.sectionImage }}" class="sectionimage" alt="image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update on `ngOnInit()` like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.onSelect(phenomTems[0]);
}
```